# CSS selector, multiple attributes, OR operator

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need your help with CSS selectors. Imagine a style HTML tag:

```
<style type="text/css">
[...selector...] {color:red;}
</style>
```

I would like to construct a selector with multiple attributes and logical operators. But I didn't found the correct syntax.

**My requirement:**
The selector should find elements, which have a 'property' attribute and this 'property' attribute equals some URL. The second condition: the elements should have a 'resource' OR 'typeof' attribute (it isn't importent, what are the values).

So I need this logical structure: A = some URL && (B || C), and it must be in one selector.
How to do this?

Comment: What sort of elements are you styling exactly? Those attributes don't exist anywhere in HTML.

Comment: I mean semantic elements annotated by RDFa technology (see this: http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-syntax/). But it is not important.

Comment: Ah yes, RDFa. Fair enough.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You will need to repeat the `property` attribute selector for each OR condition, combining each one with the second attribute selector like so:

```
[property="some URL"][resource], [property="some URL"][typeof] { color: red; }
```

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors

Comment: Is there a cleaner DRY-er solution?

Comment: @Pacerier: Not until :matches() is implemented `[property="some URL"]:matches([resources, [typeof])`

Comment: @BoltClock, Perhaps could add that into the answer.

Comment: @Pacerier: I'd rather wait until the new spec is stable and implementations actually exist. I mention this in plenty of answers already; I don't want to add more to my backlog of answers I have to edit should the spec introduce a breaking change.